# IFileOpenDialog AddText: Change size/color?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm using an `IFileOpenDialog` in folder mode so the user may select a folder containing a specific set of files.  Currently, I'm adjusting the text of the OK button to show whether the selected folder contains the files or not.  I would prefer to use a text control, so I used `IFileDialogCustomize AddText` to add my control and I'm able to adjust the actual text as needed when a `FolderChange` event occurs (because, strangely, I only *sometimes* get `ItemSelected` events when a new folder is selected).  That's all well and good but...

1. The text field is always a similar width to the **OK** and **CANCEL** buttons
2. The text field has black text on a white background, even when the dialog is shown in *Dark Mode*
3. The text wraps to fit, increasing the *height* of the field.

See what I mean?

[image: Example of bad size/color for text]

Is there any way to get this to be the correct color and a better control width or is `IFileDialogCustomize` a very weak customization feature?

As directed by Monsieur Lebeau, my condensed example code is shown below this paragraph.  If anything looks familiar, it's because I started with a function lifted from a Microsoft example.  The external `sc_CheckSimIniFileSet()` looks for the in the given folder and returns the number of required files found.  Also, just FYI, the code comes from a project that is built for ASCII instead of multibyte characters, which one might deduce from the source.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define COBJMACROS
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern "C" int sc_CheckSimIniFileSet( char *szPath );
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define FullIniCount 4
#define c_idMsg 12345
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

static LPWSTR _MakeWide( char *sz, LPWSTR wsz )
{
   DWORD len;

   len = (DWORD)strlen( sz ) + 1;
   OemToCharBuffW( sz, wsz, len );
   return wsz;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

static char *_MakeAscii( LPWSTR wsz, char *sz )
{
   DWORD len;

   len = (DWORD)lstrlenW( wsz ) + 1;
   CharToOemBuffW( wsz, sz, len );
   return sz;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CFolderSelectCallback : public IFileDialogEvents, public IFileDialogControlEvents
{
public:
   CFolderSelectCallback()
   {}

   // IUnknown
   IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface( REFIID riid, void **ppv )
   {
      static const QITAB qit[] ={
         QITABENT( CFolderSelectCallback, IFileDialogEvents ),
         QITABENT( CFolderSelectCallback, IFileDialogControlEvents ),
         { 0 },
      };
      return QISearch( this, qit, riid, ppv );
   }

   IFACEMETHODIMP_( ULONG ) AddRef() { return 3; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP_( ULONG ) Release() { return 2; }

   // IFileDialogEvents
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnFileOk( IFileDialog * /* pfd */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnFolderChanging( IFileDialog * /* pfd */, IShellItem * /* psi */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }

   IFACEMETHODIMP OnFolderChange( IFileDialog * pfd )
   {
      // Update the text of the Open/Add button here based on the selection
      IShellItem *psi;
      HRESULT hr = pfd->GetCurrentSelection( &psi );

      if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
      {
         LPWSTR wszPath;
         IFileDialogCustomize *pfdc;

         if( SUCCEEDED( pfd->QueryInterface( &pfdc ) ) )
         {
            if( SUCCEEDED( psi->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &wszPath ) ) )
            {
               char szPath[_MAX_PATH];
               _MakeAscii( wszPath, szPath );
               switch( sc_CheckSimIniFileSet( szPath ) )
               {
               default:
               case 0 :           pfdc->SetControlLabel( c_idMsg, L"Missing or invalid INI file set"     ); pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"No INI Set"  ); break;
               case 1 :           pfdc->SetControlLabel( c_idMsg, L"Only 1/4 SimLoop INI file found"     ); pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"Bad INI Set" ); break;
               case 2 :           pfdc->SetControlLabel( c_idMsg, L"Only 2/4 SimLoop INI files found"    ); pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"Bad INI Set" ); break;
               case 3 :           pfdc->SetControlLabel( c_idMsg, L"Only 3/4 SimLoop INI files found"    ); pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"Bad INI Set" ); break;
               case FullIniCount: pfdc->SetControlLabel( c_idMsg, L"Complete SimLoop INI File Set Found" ); pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"Choose"      ); break;
               }
               CoTaskMemFree( wszPath );
            }
            else
            {
               pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"GDN Error" );
            }
            pfdc->Release();
         }
         else
         {
            pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"QI Error" );
         }
         psi->Release();
      }
      else
      {
         pfd->SetOkButtonLabel( L"GCS Error" );
      }
      return S_OK;
   }

   IFACEMETHODIMP OnSelectionChange( IFileDialog * /* pfd */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnShareViolation( IFileDialog * /* pfd */, IShellItem * /* psi */, FDE_SHAREVIOLATION_RESPONSE * /* pResponse */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnTypeChange( IFileDialog * /* pfd */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnOverwrite( IFileDialog * /* pfd */, IShellItem * /* psi */, FDE_OVERWRITE_RESPONSE * /* pResponse */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }

   // IFileDialogControlEvents
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnItemSelected( IFileDialogCustomize * /* pfdc */, DWORD /* dwIDCtl */, DWORD /* dwIDItem */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnButtonClicked( IFileDialogCustomize * /* pfdc */, DWORD /* dwIDCtl */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnCheckButtonToggled( IFileDialogCustomize * /* pfdc */, DWORD /* dwIDCtl */, BOOL /* bChecked */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
   IFACEMETHODIMP OnControlActivating( IFileDialogCustomize * /* pfdc */, DWORD /* dwIDCtl */ ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" BOOL nfio_ChooseFolder( char *szPath, char *szTitle )
{
   IFileDialog   *pfd;
   LPWSTR         wszPath;
   BOOL           bResult = FALSE;
   WCHAR          wszTitle[256];

   if( SUCCEEDED( CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pfd ) ) ) )
   {
      DWORD dwOptions;

      if( SUCCEEDED( pfd->GetOptions( &dwOptions ) ) )
      {
         pfd->SetOptions( dwOptions | FOS_PICKFOLDERS );
      }
      pfd->SetTitle( _MakeWide( szTitle, wszTitle ) );

      CFolderSelectCallback foacb;
      DWORD dwCookie;

      if( SUCCEEDED( pfd->Advise( &foacb, &dwCookie ) ) )
      {
         IFileDialogCustomize *pfdc;

         if( SUCCEEDED( pfd->QueryInterface( &pfdc ) ) )
         {
            //pfdc->StartVisualGroup( c_idGrp, L"" );
            pfdc->AddText( c_idMsg, L"This is a long message, hoping to stretch the initially created control" );
            //pfdc->EndVisualGroup();
            pfdc->Release();
         }

         if( SUCCEEDED( pfd->Show( NULL ) ) )
         {
            IShellItem *psi;

            if( SUCCEEDED( pfd->GetResult( &psi ) ) )
            {
               if( !SUCCEEDED( psi->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &wszPath ) ) )
               {
                  MessageBox( NULL, "GetIDListName() failed", NULL, NULL );
               }
               else
               {
                  _MakeAscii( wszPath, szPath );
                  CoTaskMemFree( wszPath );
                  bResult = TRUE;
               }
               psi->Release();
            }
         }
         pfd->Unadvise( dwCookie );
      }
      pfd->Release();
   }
   return bResult;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow posts are expected to be self-contained. Please don't host code on an external site, as links tend to break over time. Put the code directly in the post. You should be able to reduce your code to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action with just a handful of statements that just open the dialog and add text to it. Remove anything that is not directly related to that task.

Comment: There's nothing more than IFileDialogCustomize to customize the dialog box in an official way, and yes, it has limitations.

Comment: According to a comment on Raymond Chen's blog, this problem was noticed by another user over a year ago: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211227-00/?p=106054 "*IFileDialogCustomize in dark mode does not color correctly in Windows 10 and Windows 11 ... the AddText() customizations don’t get colored as one would expect when in the dark mode theme.*"

Comment: File dialog customization is extremely limited. Options are to either put up with it, or use a subclass to try to find and fix the problems.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that this is another in an ever growing list of things Microsoft _started_ but never really _completed_ -- going back to [at least] the ListBox control from Windows 2.0 and beyond (way back when I started programming for Windows.)